# How to collide a player with walls?

Tags: javascript, game-physics, phaser-framework, 2d-games, tiled

I'm trying to create a top down shooter game and I am using Tiled to create my map. I've made my map and exported it as a .json file. I was finally able to make the map appear in my game, but I am having a hard time making the collision work.
I've been going through tutorials for hours and seem to have tried everything under the sun with no luck. I have an object layer in Tiled with the walls marked with the insert rectangle tool. I have every wall tile also marked with insert rectangle in the edit tileset menu. But I still cant get it to work. Walls are Tile Layer 1, ground is Tile Layer 2, object layer is called collision and the tile set name is tiles 48x48. Here's all my relevant code:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(1440, 960, Phaser.man, 'phaser-example', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update, render: render });

var sprite

//sounds
var music

//movement
var controls
var cursors

//shooting
var fireRate = 200;
var nextFire = 0;
var Bullets

//map
var map
var walls
var ground
//var collision


function preload() {

    game.load.audio('groove', ['sewer groove.mp3']);
    game.load.audio('gunshot', 'pistol.mp3');

    game.load.image('player', 'player lite.png');
    game.load.image('bullet', 'bullet.png');

    game.load.tilemap('map', 'sewermap.json', null, Phaser.Tilemap.TILED_JSON);
    game.load.image('tiles 48x48','tiles 48x48.png')

    
    
}


function create() {

    map = game.add.tilemap('map');
    map.addTilesetImage('tiles 48x48');
    //var tileset = map.addTilesetImage('map','tiles 48x48');
    //map.physics.arcade.enable(sprite, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

    
    ground = map.createLayer('Tile Layer 2');
    walls = map.createLayer('Tile Layer 1');
    //collision = map.createLayer('Object Layer 1')

    map.setCollisionBetween(0, 65, true, 'Tile Layer 1');

    //sprite.body.collideWorldbounds = true;


    //layer.resizeWorld();



    music = game.add.audio('groove',1,true);
    music.play();

    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

    //game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.P2JS)

    game.stage.backgroundColor = '#313131';

    bullets = game.add.group();
    bullets.enableBody = true;
    bullets.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;

    bullets.createMultiple(50, 'bullet');
    bullets.setAll('checkWorldBounds', true);
    bullets.setAll('outOfBoundsKill', true);
    
    sprite = game.add.sprite(620, 920, 'player');
    sprite.anchor.set(0.5, 0.5);

    //game.physics.p2.enable(sprite)

    game.physics.arcade.enable(sprite, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

    sprite.body.allowRotation = true;

    cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
}


function update() {

    game.physics.arcade.collider(sprite, walls);


    //console.log(sprite.rotation);
    sprite.rotation = game.physics.arcade.angleToPointer(sprite);

    if (game.input.activePointer.isDown)
    {
       fire();
    }


    //sprite.body.setZeroVelocity();

    if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.LEFT))
    {
        sprite.x -= 4;
    }
    else if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.RIGHT))
    {
        sprite.x += 4;
    }

    if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.UP))
    {
        sprite.y -= 4;
    }
    else if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.DOWN))
    {
        sprite.y += 4;
    }

    

    }

    function fire() {

    if (game.time.now > nextFire && bullets.countDead() > 0)
    {
        nextFire = game.time.now + fireRate;

        var bullet = bullets.getFirstDead();

        bullet.reset(sprite.x - 8, sprite.y - 8);

        game.physics.arcade.moveToPointer(bullet, 300);

    }

}







function render() {

    game.debug.text('Active Bullets: ' + bullets.countLiving() + ' / ' + bullets.total, 32, 32);
    game.debug.spriteInfo(sprite, 32, 450);
    //game.debug.spriteBounds(sprite);
    //game.debug.spriteBounds(bullets);
    //game.debug.body(sprite);

}
```

Comment: I wanted to take a look at this but without the image/map assets it gets pretty hard to repro the issue for me. Any chance you can quickly setup an environment with those at codesandbox and the likes?

Comment: @Nemoverflow  I did it, I´m not sure if I did it correctly, so tell me if you need something else. Thanks a lot for helping! https://codesandbox.io/s/top-down-project-8szww?file=/main.js

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I've had the chance to take a look at this, the issue should solely lie in how you're moving the main player:

```
sprite.x -= 4;
```

Collisions only fire if the body has a velocity, [the following table by samme should sum it up](https://gist.github.com/samme/cbb81dd19f564dcfe2232761e575063d)

You can apply acceleration, for the sake of example, to move the character towards the direction you're pointing at:

```
  if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.UP) || game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.W)) {
    game.physics.arcade.accelerationFromRotation(sprite.rotation, 200, sprite.body.acceleration);
  }
```

[image]

In the image I'm also applying a certain drag and reducing acceleration when nothing is pressed but that's your call:

```
  sprite.body.drag.x = 200;
  sprite.body.drag.y = 200;
```

If you wanted to strafe an idea could be at dealing with multiple presses and applying a different accelerationFromRotation accordingly (with a variety of degrees converted with Phaser.Math.degToRad)

For debug's sake, if needed, you might want to use some of the following:

```
  [...]

  walls = map.createLayer("Tile Layer 1");
  walls.debug = true;

  [...]

  function collisionHandler(obj1, obj2) {
    console.log("Colliding!", obj1, obj2)
  }
  game.physics.arcade.collide(sprite, walls, collisionHandler, null, this);
  game.debug.body(sprite);
```